# The tableView outlet from the ViewController to the UITableView is invalid. Outlets cannot be connected to repeating content

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, swift3

I am trying to add a tableview on Collection View. When I drag and drop to make the connection in the view controller class. It shows me the following error - "The tableView outlet from the ViewController to the UITableView is invalid. Outlets cannot be connected to repeating content."

Have any idea why is it happening? What can be the solution for the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tableview outlet need to be connected to the collectionview cell class(make a custom collectionview cell class).CollectionView outlet is to be connected to the ViewController class.

Answer (score 1):

Try connect `tableView` with your collection view cell not with view controller

Comment: Thanks svvoff. It helped